# C++ <algorithm> permutation

Tags: c++, algorithm, permutation

Why is this code note working (the code compiles and run fine, but is not actually showing the permutations):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long number;
    vector<long> interval;
    vector<long>::const_iterator it;

    cout << "Enter number: ";
    cin >> number;

    while(number-->0){
        interval.push_back(number);
    }

    do{
        for(it = interval.begin(); it < interval.end(); ++it){
            cout << *it << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    } while(next_permutation(interval.begin(), interval.end()));

    return (0);
}
```

But after changing this line:

```
while(next_permutation(interval.begin(), interval.end()));
```

with:

```
while(prev_permutation(interval.begin(), interval.end()));
```

Isn't permutation changing the elements in the vector by acting on positions ?

**PS:
I've edited the code now.**

Comment: you posted twice the same line (changing this line with example) and what is prev_permutation?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/prev_permutation/

Comment: `prev_permutation` is in STL `<algorithm>`.

Comment: I've just tested the source you posted (@JS Bangs: prev_permutation() is part of the STL) and everything is working in my opinion. Entering "3" lists all possible 6 combinations and so on. Can you please describe exactly what is not working? Please post your output for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Permutations are **lexicographically ordered**, that's what [`std::next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) and [`std::prev_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/prev_permutation) algorithms traverse.

Here you enter the "biggest" permutation, so there's no next one in order.

Comment: I understand now.  So if I want to generate all the permutations I will need to have all the numbers sorted. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly: sorted, and then use next_permutation. Or, reverse sorted, and then use prev_permutation.

Comment: @Andrie: Or just run both prev and next without the need to sort.

Answer (score 3):

> Isn't permutation changing the elements in the vector by acting on positions ?

No. `next_permutation` uses the ordering of the elements to determine the next permutation.

For example, if A < B < C, then the `next_permutation` of [A,B,C] (012) would be [A,C,B] (021). However, if A < C < B, then the `next_permutation` of [A,B,C] (021) would be [C,A,B] (102).

Since your vector was initially in decreasing order, it would have been the last permutation.

You could use the `std::greater` ordering to reverse the comparison direction.

```
} while(next_permutation(interval.begin(), interval.end(), greater<long>()));
//                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think next_permutation can work on positions (where will it store that info?). You need to be able to compare elements for next_permutation to work, and that is what it uses to generate the lexicographically next permutation.

Try inserting the numbers in the reverse order and see if that works.